# expecting CLOSE, found 'WHEN' near line 1 exception? How to get rid of it in HIbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using a WHEN CASE condition in my query in Java Hibernate.The query works fine in MySQL workbench,but gives me this exception in the Java Console.

```
:org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'WHEN' near line 1.
```

This is my query,

```
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();


hql.append(" SELECT ");
            hql.append(" v.year,");
            hql.append(" v.number,");
            hql.append(" ap.property,");
            hql.append(" CASE");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 1  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 2  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 3  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 4  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 5  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 6  THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 7  THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 8  THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 9  THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 10 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 11 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 12 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 13 THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 14 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 15 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 16 THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 17 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 18 THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 19 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 20 THEN AVG(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 21 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 22 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 23 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 24 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 25 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 26 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 27 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 28 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 29 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 30 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 31 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 32 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 33 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 34 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 35 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 36 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 37 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 38 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 39 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 40 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" WHEN ap.id = 41 THEN SUM(v.Month101)");
            hql.append(" END AS jan,");
            hql.append(" FROM");
            hql.append(" table1 v,");
            hql.append(" table2 ap");
            hql.append(" WHERE");
            hql.append(" v.number=01");
            hql.append(" AND v.Id = ap.id");
            hql.append(" AND v.year =2015");
            hql.append(" GROUP BY ap.property");
            hql.append(" ORDER BY v.Id");
```

I have this conditions for 12 months,Whats wrong with the syntax?Can any one explain?

Comment: `END AS jan,` There is syntax error here. Remove comma and try it.

Comment: @Samir,I think I would need it,I have similar conditions for 12 months,after 41 WHEN-CASE condiotions,I'll again have END as feb,END as mar and so on

Comment: Okay. So ensure after last Date of Dec, there is no extra comma.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago. In this case it would be short and more efficient to use `+` between the Strings.

Comment: @PeterLawrey,Thanks for the suggestion.I would implement that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error due to a stray comma after as **END AS jan**

```
hql.append(" END AS jan,");
hql.append(" FROM");
```

Remove the comma after **jan** above and check again - I guess it would work.

Comment: ,I think I would need it,I have similar conditions for 12 months,after 41 WHEN-CASE condiotions,I'll again have END as feb,END as mar and so on.I do not have comma after END as dec,after the last CASE-WHEN condition.

Comment: @NikhilBharadwaj - How about just removing it anyway?  There should not be a comma before the `FROM`.

Comment: @Stephen,Yes you are right. There should not be a comma before FROM

Answer (score 0):

Found the syntax error. Had missed one closing bracket SUM(v.Month101 ");

Thanks for the suggestions.